# What is the simplest way to get a twitter feed and get around the request limit?

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've done a few hours of reading about writing an application that queries the twitter API and authenticates with OAuth, but they all seem too complex for my simple task at hand:

I have a handful of customer websites, all showing their twitter feed on the home page, all running on the same server.  I do this by consuming the RSS feed of their tweets and output their latest tweets, formatted as HTML.

The problem is that as I gain more customers, I end up hitting the request limit near the end of the hour.

If I instead do an oauth authenicated API request for each customer, that will get me around the rate limit, but it seems overkill.  I have to get every customer to give me an oauth key, just to show their tweets on their website?  Can they even give me a key that lasts for ever?

All the oauth examples I've seen on the internet are for applications that do oauth requests all day, applications that will post to people's twitter feeds for them, etc.  My needs are much more simple, and I'm hoping someone has a simple answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the pre-built [Twitter Widgets.](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets)

You will not need to use OAuth - there are no rate limits.

The basic code looks like

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('edent').start();
</script>
```

You can create and customise a widget which shows all of a user's tweets [directly from the Twitter website](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile).

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  It seems to me that the widgets are included in the rate limit:  https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2874

Comment: True, but it's per IP. So it's 150 calls per hour from the Browser. The webserver isn't making any calls from its IP.  So, at worst, a few heavy users will see an error rather than everyone visiting the site.